# JQuery onclick not working as expected on drop down

Tags: jquery, html

Please see example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/uzgt3wmw/11/

HTML:

```
<div> HTML<br>
<li>
    <select id="Status" type="text">
        <option value="New">New</option>
        <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
    </select>
</li>
<div>
<br><br>
    JS
    <div id="jsoption"></div> 
    <button id="addOptions">Add Options</button>
```

Jquery:

```
var str1 ="<li><select id=\"Status1\" type=\"text\"><option value=\"New\">New</option><option value=\"Complete\">Complete</option></select></li>";

$("#addOptions").click( function() {
    $("#jsoption").html(str1);
}
 );

$("#Status").change( function() { alert("html ok");} );
$("#Status1").change( function() { alert("js ok");} )
```

I created 2 drop downs.

One using HTML, the other one created using a button.

Both drop downs show the same info, but the .change isn't working on id=Status1, it is working on id=Status, any idea?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Did you try it on Firefox ???

Comment: please check code, I am using Status and Status1, so both ids are unique ?

Answer (score 3):

It's because of dynamic elements. Use `on` method. Also, *your HTML is not valid!*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var str1 = "<li><select id=\"Status1\" type=\"text\"><option value=\"New\">New</option><option value=\"Complete\">Complete</option></select></li>";

  $("#addOptions").click(function() {
    $("#jsoption").html(str1);
  });

  $("#Status").change(function() {
    alert("html ok");
  });
  $(document).on("change", "#Status1", function() {
    alert("js ok");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>HTML
  <br/>
  <select id="Status" type="text">
    <option value="New">New</option>
    <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <br/>
  <br/>JS
  <div id="jsoption"></div>
  <button id="addOptions">Add Options</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @haxtbh Your JSFiddle is almost same as my SO Snippet, but with left invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `#status1` does not exist when the `change event` is set.

Just do this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#Status1", function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your second drop-down that you created by button does not exist on the Dom at page loads. So you need to use on selector for that.( earlier live was used for same purpose).

```
      $(document).on("change","#id",function(){alert(something)});
```

Hope this be of some help

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 $("#jsoption").change( function() { alert("js ok");} );
```